# Duplicating HTML5 Video into a jQuery Dialog Modal Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I currently have an HTML5 Video in the body of a page with custom controls. One of these custom controls is a POP-OUT button, that lets the user pop the video out into a resizable JQuery modal dialog window. To enable all of the custom controls, I have an external javascript that loads in all the elements and eventHandlers and functions to make the custom controls work.

Is there a way to simply duplicate the video, into the dialog window, on the fly, and ***not*** be forced to recreate all of the custom controls code for this "new" video?

I'm hoping not to have functions like `playPause()` AND `playPauseModal()`, but the technology would be smart enough to just use `playPause()` for both.

I am currently using `jquery-ui` to launch the modal dialog window.

Comment: depends on how your `playPause` code is implemented.. post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detach the parent from DOM then reinsert it into the modal dialog - it doesn't duplicate the video, but you can always use a placeholder in the background while in modal, and when closing modal window move it back.

A simple example:

```js
var hasMoved = false;

$("#move").on("click", function() {

  var parent = $("#parent");
  var player = $("#player");  // get reference to add and to keep alive

  if (hasMoved) {
    $("#modal").remove("#player"); // remove from modal container
    parent.append(player);
    $("#video")[0].play();      // video will stop, continue to play
    hasMoved = false;
  } 
  else {
    parent.remove("#player");   // remove player container and all controls inside

    $("#modal").append(player); // append to new container
    $("#video")[0].play();      // video will stop, continue to play
    hasMoved = true;
  }
  
});
```

```css
#parent {border:1px solid blue}
#modal {border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="player">
   <video id="video" width="500" height="280" preload="auto" autoplay>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
    <button>Play</button><button>Stop</button>
 </div>
</div>
<button id="move">Move --&gt;</button>
<div id="modal"></div>
```

Comment: This works fantastically, but I'm having a bit of difficulty after I reverse the process to bring the video BACK to it's original div.  I can go from original to window, and then back from window to original, but if I try to repeat the process once again, I get a **Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.** I'm placing the player back into the same div as it was originally.

Comment: @Murphy1976 sounds strange.. I updated the example above with a toggle function for the move button. Seem to work fine here, but there could perhaps be some reference(s) in your scenario preventing this. Hard to tell. See if this added method will work for you.

Comment: OH.. I didn't even see that you updated it... let me try that and I'll get back to you.